# Optgroup affecting dropdown width

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

This shouldn't be an issue and hasn't been in the past for me, I have examples that work but it may be something about how this has had to be wrapped.

```css
.section-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: block;
}

select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  color: black;
  background: red;
  outline: none;
  appearance: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.section-content {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 250px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border: solid red 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<h1>Scroll down to ensure that you get the scrollable dropdown</h1>
<p>Notice how the dropdown overhangs</p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="section-wrapper">
  <select id="selectid">
    <option value="Not Selected" disabled="" selected="">Select an option</option>
    <optgroup label="2021">
      <option value="Jan21">January 2021</option>
      <option value="Feb21">February 2021</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="2020">
      <option value="Option">January 2020</option>
      <option value="Option">February 2020</option>
      <option value="Option">March 2020</option>
      <option value="Option">April 2020</option>
      <option value="Option">May 2020</option>
      <option value="Option">June 2020</option>
      <option value="Option">July 2020</option>
      <option value="Option">August 2020</option>
      <option value="Option">September 2020</option>
      <option value="Option">October 2020</option>
      <option value="Option">November 2020</option>
      <option value="Option">December 20200</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>


  <div class="section-content">
    Content
  </div>

</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

This may be an issue with optgroup label, it is sometimes fine with more options added, without labels or with different body text.

The scrollbar doesn't fit within the width of the drop-down as shown here
[image: Current look]

The desired and correct look should be this

[image: Desired and correct look]

How can I prevent the scrollbar sitting outside of the width of the drop-down? It also hangs over without styling.

```html
<p>It's an issue here with only two options in one group</p>
<select id="monthlystatisticsmenu">
        <option value="Not Selected" disabled="" selected="">Please select a month to view statistics for</option>
  <optgroup label="2021">
    <option value="January21">January 2021</option>
    <option value="February21">February 2021</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="2020">
      <option value="January20">January 2020</option>
      <option value="February20">February 2020</option>
      <option value="March20">March 2020</option>
      <option value="April20">April 2020</option>
      <option value="May20">May 2020</option>
      <option value="June20">June 2020</option>
      <option value="July20">July 2020</option>
      <option value="August20">August 2020</option>
      <option value="September20">September 2020</option>
      <option value="October20">October 2020</option>
      <option value="November20">November 2020</option>
      <option value="December20">December 2020</option>
      </optgroup>
</select>
<br>
<p>But fine with 12, why is this and can it be fixed with all?</p>
<select id="monthlystatisticsmenu">
        <option value="Not Selected" disabled="" selected="">Please select a month to view statistics for</option>
  <optgroup label="2021">
    <option value="January21">January 2021</option>
    <option value="February21">February 2021</option>
    <option value="March21">March 2021</option>
    <option value="April21">April 2021</option>
    <option value="May21">May 2021</option>
    <option value="June21">June 2021</option>
    <option value="July21">July 2021</option>
    <option value="August21">August 2021</option>
    <option value="September21">September 2021</option>
    <option value="October21">October 2021</option>
    <option value="November21">November 2021</option>
    <option value="December21">December 2021</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="2020">
      <option value="January20">January 2020</option>
      <option value="February20">February 2020</option>
      <option value="March20">March 2020</option>
      <option value="April20">April 2020</option>
      <option value="May20">May 2020</option>
      <option value="June20">June 2020</option>
      <option value="July20">July 2020</option>
      <option value="August20">August 2020</option>
      <option value="September20">September 2020</option>
      <option value="October20">October 2020</option>
      <option value="November20">November 2020</option>
      <option value="December20">December 2020</option>
      </optgroup>
</select>
```

[image: Run over with no styling]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only item missing from your code was `text-indent`. By adding this, the offset seen in the select options disappeared when tested in Firefox and Safari. I also modified the width of the containing div to 80% in order to demonstrate that it wasn't the viewport window constraining elements. I also added some other minor styling to pull the space in.

A caveat, though, is that the display of select elements is often overridden by the browser, so the user experience will be different in Webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari) than Firefox.

```css
.section-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: block;
}

select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  color: black;
  background: red;
  outline: none;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

select optgroup {
  text-indent: 0.5em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.section-content {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 250px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border: solid red 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<h1>Scroll down to ensure that you get the scrollable dropdown</h1>
<p>Notice how the dropdown overhangs</p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="section-wrapper">
  <select id="monthlystatisticsmenu">
    <option value="Not Selected" disabled="" selected="">Please select a month to view statistics for</option>
    <optgroup label="2021">
      <option value="January21">January 2021</option>
      <option value="February21">February 2021</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="2020">
      <option value="January20">January 2020</option>
      <option value="February20">February 2020</option>
      <option value="March20">March 2020</option>
      <option value="April20">April 2020</option>
      <option value="May20">May 2020</option>
      <option value="June20">June 2020</option>
      <option value="July20">July 2020</option>
      <option value="August20">August 2020</option>
      <option value="September20">September 2020</option>
      <option value="October20">October 2020</option>
      <option value="November20">November 2020</option>
      <option value="December20">December 2020</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>


  <div class="section-content">
    Content
  </div>

</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

This still doesn't fully fix the issue in Chrome as mentioned, a universal fix is needed.
[image: Chrome]

Comment: Chrome is the one I'm having the issue with, if you see the last section in the first question on chrome you can see the issue without style.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? Was just tested in v.88.0 (latest) on macOS.

Comment: 88.0.4324.150 stable and 89.0.4389.47 beta. I'm getting the issue in both.

Comment: Is this on Windows?

Comment: Yeah it is, I'm wondering if it's an OS issue but I've seen the dropdown perform properly before.

Comment: Hmm. It may be—as some browsers give little options to style the drowpdown options to begin with—sometimes claimed to be for usability reasons.

Comment: Close to giving up. It sits on the outside as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8KI0.png) with fewer than six options in each optgroup. It also does the same [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QgKW.png)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228680/discussion-between-karolus-and-helpmeplease).